# Understanding trasferPropsTo

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I couldn't make out that `transferPropsTo` is for, reading [the docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#transferpropsto).

The example given example looks like this:

```
var Avatar = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return this.transferPropsTo(
      <img src={"/avatars/" + this.props.userId + ".png"} userId={null} />
    );
  }
});

// <Avatar userId={17} width={200} height={200} />
```

I don't see the difference between this and:

```
return (
    <img src={"/avatars/" + this.props.userId + ".png"} />
)
```

What else I don't get:

- what's the `userId={null}` supposed to illustrate?
- `<Avatar />` is passed a `width=` and `height=`. What for? What happens to them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `transferPropsTo` method is used to copy properties from one object to another, the docs are trying to explain exactly which properties are copied.

> what's the `userId={null}` supposed to illustrate?

Settings made explicitly don't get overwritten by `transferPropsTo`, so it is showing that even though the `userId` is set on `Avatar`, that won't get copied over since `userId` is explicitly set to null on the `img`.

> Avatar is passed a width= and height=. What for? What happens to them?

Those are the two properties which are "transferred" over to the `img`, so the example is roughly equivalent to:

```
return (
    <img src={"/avatars/" + this.props.userId + ".png"} // explicit
         userId={null}                        // explicit, not overwritten
         width={this.props.width}             // copied
         height={this.props.height}           // copied
         />
)
```

The difference between that and the original example is that the code which constructs the Avatar controls which additional properties are set on the `img`, rather than the `Avatar`'s render method itself.

Comment: Awesome, makes much more sense when you look at it from the "docs are trying to explain exactly which properties are copied" angle. Perfect, thanks!